# Is Highschool of the Dead on hiatus again?

Tags: highschool-of-the-dead

I was really happy when I heard that HoTD would be continued. And even happier when the first new chapter actually came. but now after several months of waiting there still has been no other chapter. So my question is, has HoTD gone on hiatus again ?

Comment: Since [the mangaka passed away](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/news/2017-03-26/high-school-of-the-dead-manga-creator-daisuke-sato-passes-away-at-52/.113968), we will never see the continuation of this story

Comment: @Darjeeling Very sad news indeed.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Quoted from [a post on Facebook](https://www.facebook.com/permalink.php?story_fbid=577033532348809&id=119168144802019). The post explains why the authors release chapter 30 after so many gap, all the reasons for delay and whether they will release more chapters or not:

> Alright folks, after WEEKS of intense investigation, convincing, pleading, smooth talking, and talking to "people who know people" in Japan... I'd like to clear things up about the situation of H.O.T.D. from the past 2 years, now, and the foreseeable future:
>
> - The reason for the manga's 2 year hiatus was for 2 reasons:
>
>   1. Writer Daisuke Sato had a heart disease that required a lot of treatment, surgery, and recovery.
>   2. Because of the earthquake that happened in Japan, he didn't think an apocalypse story was appropriate to continue at the time until Japan recovered from it.
> - During those 2 years, Daisuke and Shouji were VERY surprised to find out that H.O.T.D. had become so popular worldwide.
> - The purpose to release Chapter 30 was for multiple reasons: to get the Satos back to work on the story, to see if the manga was still popular, and finally to let fans know that they haven't forgotten about it.
> - In May, Daisuke started preparing rough drafts for chapters 31 and beyond and throughout this summer he will be working on finalizing on where the story will go, and research in terms of locations, military, weapons, and vehicles... as stated last year at the anime convention in Germany.
> - Shouji went back to work on Fire Fire Fire: Black Sword to make himself get used to working on multiple stories. Plus he had a desire to go back to that story anyway.
> - Sales for Chapter 30 when it was released digitally were going "surprisingly well for a single chapter" and that future chapters WILL be released on the same day in both the US and Japan.
> - The Japanese Publisher Kadokawa is currently deciding if they want to release a chapter of Triage X and H.O.T.D. at the same time or a bi-monthly pattern.
> - The next chapters of H.O.T.D. are VERY crucial on deciding if the series will end with an 8th volume or continue when they go on sale. If you American H.O.T.D. fans don't buy digital copies, they'll take it as a sign of losing interest and the series will end prematurely... So don't go bitching and whining if that does happen. It'll be your fault for not supporting the creators.
>
> So there you have it, a lot of hard work and contacting the righ[t people]
>
> Credit to Joey Senna McRae for gathering all this info.

---

**EDIT** : As comment above by [Darjeeling](https://anime.stackexchange.com/users/2869/darjeeling) the mangaka [**Daisuke Satou passed away**](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/news/2017-03-26/high-school-of-the-dead-manga-creator-daisuke-sato-passes-away-at-52/.113968), so we probably will never see the continuation of the story.